# Redirect ugly URLs to their cleaner version and/or rewrite them at the same time

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been searching for ways to change `http://www.mysite.com/about.html` to `http://www.mysite.com/about` but had no luck so far.

Is this possible?

Comment: Change where? In your php/html code?

Comment: no, change the URL via .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html
```

Lines 2-3 take care of the case when the *original request* contains **.html**. This request is translated to a 301 redirect via `[R=301]` flag and further processing is terminated via the `[L]` flag.

Line 4 acts as a condition for line 5. Line 5 does the *normal* URL rewriting. I just appends **.html** to any URL does not end with **.html**.

## Understanding the recursion:

Without the `RewriteCond` and `[L]` flags, the rules will create an infinite loop.

1. A request such as **about.html** becomes **about** on line 3 and becomes **about.html** on line 5. `[R]` prevents that.
2. A request such as **about** will become **about.html** on line 5, then mod_rewrite processes this URL again so that line 3 will change it back to **about**; but the `RewriteCond` will prevent that because it checks the *original* request sent by the browser, not the re-written one.

Comment: still does not do anything, I do have conditions set up in the htaccess file so that if someone uses mysite.com it automatically changes to www.mysite.com so I definetly have it in the right place.. thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I see the about page but what I was after is if a user has bookmarked mysite.com/about.html and clicks the bookmark that the address bar shows them mysite.com/about NOT mysite.com/about.html

Comment: Oh, that is something else. Its called *301 redirect via .htaccess* and basically its implementing the same rule the other way round. This almost always causes a cycle/infinite redirects and very tricky. I'll see if I can find a solution.

Comment: please note i do not have lots of pages so im happy to write a rule for each page ie change about.html to /about - contact.html to /contact etc. Thanks again

Comment: @Bob: I've edited my answer. Seems to be working on my system.

Comment: it sort of works..apart from the it has no styling (althoguh viewing source it still hass the css in there) and al lthe images are show as dead images (white box with red cross) damn! thanks so much for all your help so far...any idea on this one? :(

Comment: Well... its fairly understandable why this happens. The 4th line adds `.html` to everything that does not have it. So `foo.css` becomes `foo.css.html`, `bar.gif` becomes `bar.gif.html` and so on. It needs little thinking.

Comment: is there a way to stop it applying the rules to folders? such as the css folder and images folder? sorry for being a pain!

Comment: I've revised my answer. See it it helps.

Comment: nailed it! thank you ever so much Salman A - very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: try checking your filepaths, etc, ... works fine @ my localhost

Comment: what do you mean by checking filepaths?